# Rails 4 nested has_many with where clauses along the way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

The relationship is as follows.

```
Client -> has_many :analytics
Client -> has_many :metrics, through: :analytics
Analytic -> has_many :metrics
```

Now I cannot simply do a `Client.find(1).analytics.where(condition).metrics` as I get this error:

```
undefined method `metrics' for #<Analytic::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00000002e31a50>
```

What I have found I can do is the following but it seems bulky and not very much the rails way:

```
analytics = client.analytics.where(conditions).select(:id)
metrics = Metric.where(analytic_id: analytics)
```

Is there a way to chain this together in a more sensible way like I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it seems like you want `metrics`, so you should start there.

You need to query conditions on the association as well.

And join the association to query against your condition.

Try something like this:

```
metrics = Metric.joins(analytic: [:client]).where(analytic:{ conditions, client_id: client })
```

## Edit

I think we can make the query more elegant.

Let me know if this works, going off the top of my head here.

```
client = Client.find(1)
metrics = client.metrics.joins(:analytic).where(analytics: {conditions})
```

Comment: Thanks. Not really any more elegant than what I had attempted before but definitely more readable. Both solutions result in 2 SQL operations (mine a `select` and a `where in select` and yours a `select` and a `join`.

Comment: thanks to the `has_many through` associaton you don't even need the join on the clients. `c = Client.find(1) ` will suffice with `m = c.metrics.joins(:analytic).where(analytics: {cond})`